# Change CSS based on time of date or time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a question about loading a JavaScript that changes the CSS based on the time of day or date.

Question: How can I cache the images so that they do not load from page to page? The Script works fine and adds the class to the body and header based on the time of day. However, when a user clicks the next page of the website, it reloads the same CSS Class and causes the site to flash to white before loading the CSS.

I've placed the script at the bottom of the page and in the header. Yet it still flashes on every page that loads the script. Is there away to prevent the script from loading everytime the user goes from page to page?

Here is the Js Code.

```
function TimeOfDaySiteChange() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();

    if (n < 5) {
        // midnight
        night();
    } else if (n > 16 && n < 20) {
        // If time is between 5PM &ndash; 8PM sunset theme to 'body'
        dusk();
    } else if (n > 19) {
        // If time is 8PM 
        night();
    } else if (n > 8) {
        // If time is 9AM
        daytime();
    } else {
        // Else use 'dawn' theme
        dawn();
    }
}

function dawn() {
    jQuery('body').addClass('sunrise_bg');
    jQuery('#header_masthead').addClass('sunrise_masthead_bg');
}

function daytime() {
    jQuery('body').addClass('day_bg');
    jQuery('#header_masthead').addClass('day_masthead_bg');
}

function dusk() {
    jQuery('body').addClass('sunset_bg');
    jQuery('#header_masthead').addClass('sunset_masthead_bg');
}

function night() {
    jQuery('body').addClass('night_bg');
    jQuery('#header_masthead').addClass('night_masthead_bg');
}

function init() {
    TimeOfDaySiteChange();
}

window.onload = init;
```

I've also tried it without `window.onload`

Comment: have you tried placing your code in a document ready function?

Comment: You don't need to add a class to #header_masthead, just do body.sunrise_bg #header_masthead {}

Comment: Regarding the flash; before your JS has loaded, run and eventually added a class the browser will show the default page. I'd add the class on the server side instead.

Comment: @powerbuoy Why would you do that? The server knows nothing about the client's time

Comment: Oh, that's true. Didn't think about that. But the reason I'd do that should hopefully be obvious (had it worked). I'd consider setting a cookie with JS that can be used on the server for subsequent loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to put this as the very first thing in your body and remove the `window.onload`.  You would need to tweak your css slightly so that you only change the class on the `body`:

```
.sunrise_bg #header_masthead{
```

instead of having a class on the `#header_masthead`.

Then run `TimeOfDaySiteChange()` as the very first thing in your body.

By using `onload` you are waiting for the entire page to load before applying your class.

---

Alternatively, if you're using html5, you could change your code to add the class to the `html` element and place your javascript early in the `head` of your document.  This may be slightly faster.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "better" to put it as the first thing in `<head>` and use `html` instead of `body` for selectors?

Comment: @Ian  I don't believe that's valid in html4 but seems to be in html5.

Comment: What's not valid? Giving the `<html>` element a `class`?

Comment: @ian Yes, in html4 and xhtml the `html` element cannot have a `class` attribute.

Comment: Interesting! I change my original comment to be "With HTML5, wouldn't it be ..." :)

Comment: @ian fair enough.  I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: Haha it's no different to me. It just seems *that* much quicker, but I don't know if it would make that big of a difference

Answer (score 1):

> Is there away to prevent the script from loading everytime the user
>   goes from page to page?

In short, no. Your current implementation dynamically adds classes (based on the time of day) with Javascript. You need the Javascript to run on every page in order for the classes to be added.

You can use the method as suggested by James https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281934/2174104 to minimise the time it takes for the function to run, but there is no way to load the background colour once and keep it if your site uses separate html documents.